# Xcode 10 gets stops automatically after running when breakpoint is enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, xcode10

In Xcode when I run my project it gets stop automatically soon after started running. This is happening when I keep a breakpoint for some code. The weird thing is that, it is happening for a some particular class only. If I enable a breakpoint in other classes then it is running and working fine. I am not able to run Xcode and debug with the issues.

I tried to fix this issue by clearing all the breakpoints and quit the Xcode and run it again. But as soon as I enable breakpoint in that particular class Xcode again got stopped.

I am totally blank in figuring out the problem for this issue. If any one has come across with this issue kindly share your experience to resolve this. Currently I'm using Xcode 10.2. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

For certain code, this happens. This is a known issue and I had submitted a bug report. For the time being, use print statements and add breakpoints before and after the issue code path. The problem is with the lldb rpc server crashing, which exits the debug mode. You can find it in the issue crash log under `~/Library/Log/DiagnosticReports` folder.